# LibGDX strange camera behaviour

Tags: opengl, java, libgdx, camera

I'm currently doing my final assessment for my study Game Development. I'm currently facing a real weird (maybe explainable) result from my camera.

I just set up my scene with alot of tiles and a character. When I set up the camera's position and direction, I experience something strange. The camera is tilted somewhat, and I can't explain why that is happening.

This is looking pretty good. Except for when I move the camera, the tilting is becoming worse.

- Is this behaviour I should expect from the camera?
- I made sure the camera is never rotated, is there any possibility the models are slightly rotated?
- I use LibGDX with exported FBX files from 3Ds Max, converted to LibGDX's format "G3DB", are there any known issues with that?

Comment: Closed because external resources are no longer valid, making the post very hard to understand. You could reupload them to [StackExchange's imgur account](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2721/40264) to avoid this issue in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Camera**

The problem might be the up vector of the Camera. This up vector is what determines the roll of the camera. As the camera rolls then what it considers up will change with it.

You can set it directly to (0,1,0) using "mCamera.up.set(Vector3.Y)". This should fix the tilt.

You are setting the camera lookAt using "mCamera.lookAt(...)" which may be changing the up vector. You might want to try mCamera.normalizeUp() right after to see if that sorts anything.

**Model**

Double check the way you create the world matrix for the model and make sure you are not applying any rotations. If you are remove them. If it looks right with all of them removed then you know the problem is there.

Comment: It was indeed the up vector that changed! I can't identify where it changes, but I use 'mCamera.up.set(Vector3.Y);' right after the lookAt, which fixes the issue. Thanks alot!